# How to put this in graphing or grid paper and solve

Tags: circles

On a chean sheet of grid paper, paste some small pictures of objects such that they are positioned at different coordinates. Then, draw circles that contain them pictures. Using the pictures and the circles driven on the grid formulate and solve problems involving the equation of the circle, then solve them.

Comment: More context would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a circle centered at $(a, b)$ is $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$where $r$ denotes the radius of the circle. I recommend using DESMOS because you can add images and graphs very easily. You can add images by going to the + button and clicking "Image."